# Do elves use money?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, elves

Is the use of money by elves mentioned anywhere in Tolkien's Legendarium? It is known that men, hobbits and dwarves used money, but what about elves?

Apparently some of the elven kingdoms had some kind of foreign trade with other peoples (if I remember correctly, the Mirkwood elves traded with Lake-town) but was money used within elven society?

Comment: Perhaps, but there's no direct evidence of this. But, note, that while money certainly exists in Middle-Earth (e.g., Butterbur paying silver pennies to replace the Hobbits' horses) it is very rarely mentioned even in human societies. I think we're free to fill in the answer.

Comment: I can't believe there _isn't_ a handful of manuscript pages where Tolkien quickly jotted down the monetary systems of Men and Dwarves before starting a long digression to explain why the Noldor coins had completely different denominations ...

Comment: *Similarly farthing has been used for the
four divisions of the Shire, because the Hobbit word tharni was
an old word for 'quarter' seldom used in ordinary language,
where the word for 'quarter' was tharantin 'fourth part'. In
Gondor tharni was used for a silver coin, the fourth part of the
castar (in Noldorin the canath or fourth part of the mirian)* ~ HoME #12. The elves (or at least the Noldorin) appear to have their own words for various coins. I'm not sure if that proves that they actually *used* them.

Comment: Probably the best places to look for examples are the Nogrod episode where they kill the king in his treasury and in the sack of Nargothrond. I think in a early revision though, Glaurung's heap of treasure is described as "golden vessels and unwrought gold." Tolkien's drawing of Smaug features coins, but that was a Dwarven city. Then again, with all the traffic of goods between dwarves and elves, the elves had to pay the Dwarves with *something*.

Comment: @lfurini Tolkien didn't care much about money in Middle-earth. While there's now https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economy_of_Middle-earth I still wonder why. It's a rather minor topic in his books.

Comment: @Valorum Could you provide a more specific citation? (I don't have an electronic version of HoME #12 to search, and the index is limited to people and place names.) It's odd that Gondor and Noldorin would be mentioned together, as by the time Gondor had been conceived, what started as the Noldorin language had become the Sindarin. Gondor might have used various Sindarin words for coinage regardless of whether or not Elves used money.

Comment: @chepner - That's literally the entire citation and only mentioned in passing...

Comment: @Valorum No, I meant what page (or at least chapter) does it appear on?

Comment: @chepner - It's marked as note #41 in the section *"The Languages at the end of the Third Age."*

Comment: @Valorum - In this context Noldorin just refers to the language that Tolkien would later decide to rename to Sindarin, an elvish language that was in regular usage by the Men of Gondor. I don't think it's an indicator that elves ever used those words to refer to coins. (Also §41 here would be "paragraph 41", not "note 41". It's just a notation Christopher uses to number paragraphs for ease of reference.)

Comment: When Glaurung + orcs plundered Nargothrond, Galurung lied down to rest on a hoard of valuables. It's not specific what the hoard contained IIRC, but surely there had to be money in it? It would be a strange dragon hoard without an abundance of coins.

Comment: Thingol also _hired_ dwarves to make Nauglamír, then refused to pay them.

Answer (score -1):

Not likely.

I have the impression the Elves did not use money, since they made what they needed for themselves, and gave extra away freely. Ownership wasn't important to them. In Valinor they made gemstones, according to *The Silmarillion*:

> they devised tools for the cutting and shaping of gems, and carved them in many forms. They hoarded them not, but gave them freely, and by their labour enriched all Valinor.

They never offered to buy the ships of the Teleri: "no ship would they lend". So they stole the ships.

They did like to hoard treasure, but their treasure was likely things made, not coins. Thranduil, per *The Hobbit* (emphasis mine):

> In ancient days they had had wars with some of the dwarves, whom they accused of **stealing their treasure**. It is only fair to say that the dwarves gave a different account, and said that they only took what was their due, for the elf-king had bargained with them to **shape his raw gold and silver, and had afterwards refused to give them their pay**. **If the elf-king had a weakness it was for treasure, especially for silver and white gems**; and though his hoard was rich, he was ever eager for more, since he had not yet as great a treasure as other elf-lords of old. His people neither mined nor worked metals or jewels, nor did they bother much with trade or with tilling the earth.

Elves give many gifts, and never ask for payment. The elves of Lothlorien gave the Fellowship many gifts, and payment was never mentioned. Elrond's house hosts many people, and no one is mentioned to pay for his hospitality. No payment was mentioned when Frodo, Sam, Merry, and Pippin were spirited away to Gildor's elven halls and provided a wonderful meal.

Good intentions from good people mean, in Middle-earth, that payment is unnecessary. To each according to his need, if free from evil influence.

Comment: Good points, but I think you go too far. The behavior of the High Elves to the Fellowship is hardly representative of general elvish behavior towards generic humans. In *The Hobbit*, the elves of Mirkwood certainly have a vigorous trade with Laketown and that certainly wasn't based on gift-giving! (Even if the Elves were so minded, the Master of Laketown wasn't.)

Comment: @MarkOlson, "His people neither mined nor worked metals or jewels, nor did they bother much with trade or with tilling the earth." So they likely did NOT use money, and might well have considered it exchanging gifts.